compare numbers in range again another number
I have not programed with delphi in MANY year. In fact I am using Delphi 2010. Anyway, I have tried to find an answer online but just can't seem to find an answer. Basically I have two values 1.)441941110 and 2.)1202515556435. Value 1 can change by 10's or 100 million but number 2 does not change. I want to compare the #1 within a range and make sure it is always less than #2. something like
if (#1 +- 100000000) <> #2 then
begin
showmessage('these number are different');
end;
Here is an example
#1
5|8|1
7|2|3   these numbers in a 3x3 grid can change to be 1-9 making there total between 9-81
1|9|2
#2
15|2|22
99|1|3  these numbers in a 3x3 grid can change to be 1-99 making there total between 9-891
10|17|87
